# Is there any way to automate dynamic code generation in Java?

Tags: java, loops, dynamic-programming, code-generation

I want something in my code that will generate loops and its corresponding body dynamically. My code right now looks like this for which I have explicitly defined each loop and loop body, each of which runs based on a variable "len"'s value. How can I change it so that the loop codes such as those that I have written for each condition are generated dynamically?

```java
ArrayList<String> mapAll(String input){
        int len = input.length();
        ArrayList<String> outputs= new ArrayList<>();
        //String[] outputs = new String[len];
        ArrayList<String> outputStrings= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <len ; i++)
            outputs.add(mapOne(Character.toString(input.charAt(i))));

        if (len == 1)
            for (int i = 0; i <outputs.get(len -1).length() ; i++)
                    outputStrings = outputs;

        else if (len == 2)
            for (int i = 0; i <outputs.get(len-2).length() ; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < outputs.get(len - 1).length(); j++)
                    outputStrings.add(Character.toString(outputs.get(len - 2).charAt(i)) + outputs.get(len - 1).charAt(j));



        else if(len == 3)
            for (int i = 0; i <outputs.get(len-3).length(); i++)
                for (int j = 0; j <outputs.get(len-2).length(); j++)
                    for (int k = 0; k <outputs.get(len-1).length(); k++)
                        outputStrings.add(Character.toString(outputs.get(len-3).charAt(i)) + outputs.get(len - 2).charAt(j) + outputs.get(len - 1).charAt(k));


        else if(len==4)
            for (int i = 0; i < outputs.get(len-4).length(); i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < outputs.get(len-3).length(); j++)
                    for(int k = 0; k < outputs.get(len-2).length(); k++)
                        for(int l = 0; l < outputs.get(len-1).length(); l++)
                            outputStrings.add(Character.toString(outputs.get(len-4).charAt(i)) + outputs.get(len-3).charAt(j) + outputs.get(len-2).charAt(k)+ outputs.get(len-1).charAt(l));


        return outputStrings;
    }
```

Implementation of mapOne method:

```java
   private String mapOne(String in){
        String out;
        switch (in){
            case "a":
                out = "a"+"q"+"w"+"s"+"z";
                break;
            case "b":
                out = "b"+"g"+"h"+"v"+"n"+" ";
                break;
            case "c":
                out = "c"+"d"+"f"+"x"+"v"+" ";
                break;
            case "d":
                out = "d"+"e"+"r"+"s"+"f"+"x"+"c";
                break;
            case "e":
                out = "e"+"w"+"r"+"s"+"d";
                break;
            case "f":
                out = "f"+"r"+"t"+"d"+"g"+"c"+"v";
                break;
            case "g":
                out = "g"+"t"+"y"+"f"+"h"+"v"+"b";
                break;
            case "h":
                out = "h"+"y"+"u"+"g"+"j"+"b"+"n";
                break;
            case "i":
                out = "i"+"u"+"o"+"j"+"k";
                break;
            case "j":
                out = "j"+"u"+"i"+"h"+"k"+"n"+"m";
                break;
            case "k":
                out = "k"+"i"+"o"+"j"+"l"+"m";
                break;
            case "l":
                out = "l"+"o"+"p"+"k";
                break;
            case "m":
                out = "m"+"j"+"k"+"n"+" ";
                break;
            case "n":
                out = "n"+"h"+"j"+"b"+"m"+" ";
                break;
            case "o":
                out = "o"+"i"+"p"+"k"+"l";
                break;
            case "p":
                out = "p"+"o"+"l";
                break;
            case "q":
                out = "q"+"w"+"a";
                break;
            case "r":
                out = "r"+"e"+"t"+"d"+"f";
                break;
            case "s":
                out = "s"+"w"+"e"+"a"+"d"+"z"+"x";
                break;
            case "t":
                out = "t"+"r"+"y"+"f"+"g";
                break;
            case "u":
                out = "u"+"y"+"i"+"h"+"j";
                break;
            case "v":
                out = "v"+"f"+"g"+"c"+"b"+" ";
                break;
            case "w":
                out = "w"+"q"+"e"+"a"+"s";
                break;
            case "x":
                out = "x"+"s"+"d"+"z"+"c"+" ";
                break;
            case "y":
                out = "y"+"t"+"u"+"g"+"h";
                break;
            case "z":
                out = "z"+"a"+"s"+"x";
                break;
            case " ":
                out = " "+"x"+"c"+"v"+"b"+"n"+"m";
                break;
            default:
                out = "#";


        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Recursion may be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @assylias How can I do that? Please provide me some hints. Thanks. I actually am a newb. in coding.

Comment: Your first loop (`len==1`) doesn't make any sense. You are just assigning the same thing to the same variable in a loop without any dependence on `i`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic There actually is a dependence on `i`. The array list `outputs` is added with the string output obtained from mapOne function for each individual character of the `input` string.

Comment: Not in your `len==1` case.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash You are absolutely correct. Disregarding that one, could you somehow tell me how I can automate this whole thing to generate loops for different values of `len` dynamically rather than the static way I have done for different lengths?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Please pay no mind to that particular loop. Is there some way to dynamically generate these loops based on the value of `len`. These loop bodies show the way I would want them to be generated. Can it be done?

Comment: As suggested in the first comment. Use a recursive method.  `recursiveMethod(List<String> outputs, int len, int index) { for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {  // do something  recursiveMethod(outputs, len, i); }`

Comment: I will look more into recursive methods then. Thanks @Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean version with streams:

```java
static ArrayList<String> mapAll1(String input) {
    int len = input.length();
    ArrayList<String> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
    //String[] outputs = new String[len];
    ArrayList<String> outputStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        outputs.add(mapOne(Character.toString(input.charAt(i))));

    if (len == 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < outputs.get(len - 1).length(); i++)
            outputStrings = outputs;

    else {
        outputStrings = IntStream
                .range(0, len)
                // get last n strings from outputs, starts from last
                .mapToObj(i -> outputs.get(len - (i + 1)))
                // transform List<String> into List<List<String>>,
                .map(x -> new ArrayList<>(x.chars()
                        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                )
                // reduce
                .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (acc, list) -> new ArrayList<>(
                        acc.isEmpty() ? list : list.stream()
                                .flatMap(prefix -> acc.stream()
                                        .map(tail -> prefix + tail)
                                ).collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }

    return outputStrings;
}
```

The main part written in old way with further explanation

```java
if (len == 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.get(len - 1).length(); i++)
        outputStrings = outputs;

else {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tokenizeStrings = new ArrayList();
    // get last n strings from outputs, starts from last
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // transform List<String> into List<List<String>>,
        tokenizeStrings.add( new ArrayList<>(outputs.get(len - (i + 1)).chars()
                .mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }

    outputStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    // reduce
    for (ArrayList<String> list: tokenizeStrings) {
        if (outputStrings.isEmpty()) {
            // first iteration just makes a copy
            outputStrings = list;
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String prefix : list) {
                // for the rest iterations use string 'prefix' from current list
                // and add it in front of every string from main list 'outputStrings'
                for (String tail : outputStrings) {
                    temp.add(prefix + tail);
                }
            }
            // replace outputStrings with temp list
            outputStrings = temp;
        }
    }
}

return outputStrings;
```

Comment: I tried using this but I am not getting any output for strings of size greater than 1 character. Thanks for taking the time to write the answer. These lambda expressions get over my head. Is there a way to achieve this without using them?

Comment: I had a bug, try now, also i add a version without streams @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: @Iczapski For some reason, it's not producing any output for greater than 1 again. Shall I post the full code? That might give you a better context. I really appreciate you helping me out. :)

Comment: I added my test, you can check if i catched your situation @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: OK. I see that i misunderstand what you want to do and do completely different. Can you add implementation for `mapOne`.As it was said earlier i think that it should be done with recursion @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: Can you say what is the output in `mapOne` for example for "a"? @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: It's `aqwsz` for `a`.

Comment: I added new version, please check it @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: Wow, @Iczapski it really worked. Please brief me about how you solved this. [Edit: There is a minor problem though, how do I make it so that it takes white space as input too? As of now, it disregards everything after white space, meaning its shows result only for `red` when I provide the input string as `red viper`]

Comment: I added cleaner version with explanations. Thanks for 'accepted' if the answer is helpful you can also  'voted up' it . With 'white space' i didn't quite catch the problem. @MaverickD.Aece

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. Thanks again. I solved it by using `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.